# How to use php Explode and filter posts by taxonomy (using ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hi there im using Wordpress with the Advanced Custom fields plugin, and of course PHP.

Im struggling to understand how to filter my post by a chosen taxonomy, selected on the back using Advanced Custom fields

Im not sure how to use explode to create a list separated by commas for my chosen "terms"

```
<?php if( get_row_layout() == 'post_grid' ):?>
            <div class="post-grid">
            <style>
            .post-grid {
    display: grid; gap: 2%; grid-template-columns: repeat(<?php the_sub_field('post_per_row'); ?>,minmax(0,1fr));}.single-item a img {width: 100%; height: <?php the_sub_field('post_image_height')?>; object-fit: cover;}</style>
            <?php if( get_sub_field('post_type_choice')):
            $PostTypeChoice = get_sub_field('post_type_choice');
            $PostsPerPage = get_sub_field('post_per_page');
            $categoryTag = get_sub_field('category_tag');
            $categoryTagTerm = get_sub_field('category_tag_term');
            $postGridItems = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => $PostTypeChoice,
            'posts_per_page' => $PostsPerPage,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $categoryTag,
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array(explode(',', $categoryTagTerm))
        )
    )
            ));
            while($postGridItems->have_posts()) {
               $postGridItems->the_post(); ?> 
            <div class="single-item">
                <?php if(get_sub_field('with_image') == '1'):?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a><?php endif;?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title();?></h2></a><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span>Read More..</span></a></div>
            <?php }
            endif;
                ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

I have try simplifying the 'terms' part to this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $categoryTag
        )
    )
```

still i get no results i can get it to work if i use just 'cat' ie:

```
    'cat' => $categoryTag
```

but i wanna be able to filer it using a variable/object.

sorry if this is basic stuff but im learning

im trying to create a simple post grid for use on my clients websites, that is editable on the backend using Advanced Custom fields

***UPDATE***
I have updated my code, but still it does not work, please what am i doing wrong? help!?

```
<?php if( get_row_layout() == 'post_grid' ):?>
            <div class="post-grid">
            <style>
            .post-grid {
    display: grid; gap: 2%; grid-template-columns: repeat(<?php the_sub_field('post_per_row'); ?>,minmax(0,1fr));}.single-item a img {width: 100%; height: <?php the_sub_field('post_image_height')?>; object-fit: cover;}</style>
            <?php 
            $PostTypeChoice = get_sub_field('post_type_choice');
            $PostsPerPage = get_sub_field('post_per_page');
            $categoryTag = get_sub_field('category_tag');
            $categoryTagTerm = get_sub_field('category_tag_term');
            $categoryTagTerm_array = explode( ',', $categoryTagTerm );
            $postGridArgs = array(
                'post_type' => $PostTypeChoice,
                'posts_per_page' => $PostsPerPage,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => $categoryTag,
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => array($categoryTagTerm_array),
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        )
                )
        );
    $postGridItems = new WP_Query($postGridArgs);
            while($postGridItems -> have_posts()): $postGridItems -> the_post();
        ?> 
            <div class="single-item">
                <?php if(get_sub_field('with_image') == '1'):?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a><?php endif;?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title();?></h2></a><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span>Read More..</span></a></div>
           </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

***UPDATE 2***

the above code works fine if i manually enter this

```
'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'category',
                       'field'    => 'slug',
                       'terms'    => array('New Cat, Uncategorised'),
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        )
                )
```

but not if i use variables (like below), although the output of the variables appears to be correct?

```
'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                       'taxonomy' => $categoryTag,
                       'field'    => 'slug',
                       'terms'    => array($categoryTagTerm_array),
                            'operator' => 'IN'
                        )
                )
```

please can someone help me??

Comment: if you change `'terms'=> array($categoryTagTerm_array),` to `'terms'=> $categoryTagTerm_array,` what happens then? Either way check what categoryTagTerm_array contains, if its a comma separated string you have to split it with explode to create an array, if its an array you don't need to enclose it further

Comment: Hi there, i did do that originally. still didn't work.

Comment: there is this in the code:
```$categoryTagTerm = get_sub_field('category_tag_term');
            $categoryTagTerm_array = explode( ',', $categoryTagTerm );```
this "get_sub_field('category_tag_term');" returns "New Cat, Uncategorised"

Comment: You're using `'field' => 'slug'` but trying to match **names**, to match names you need to use `'field' => 'name'`

Comment: that didn't work either, this is so frustrating. :(

Comment: so i just did ```echo $categoryTagTerm_array; echo $categoryTagTerm; echo $categoryTag;```
and
$categoryTagTerm_array returned nothing
$categoryTagTerm returned the word "array"
$categoryTag returned the word "array"
which is super strange, because using  ```get_sub_field();``` returns exactly what i want.
weird

Comment: Im sooo confused, its breaking my head:
```<?php echo (get_sub_field('category_tag_term'));?>``` returns ***"New Cat, Uncategorised"***
```echo $categoryTagTerm;``` returned the word ***"array"***
so if im using this ```$categoryTagTerm = get_sub_field('category_tag_term');```
***why are they not the same?***